# QGIS doesn't like the number 6?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Something seems to be wrong with the layout manager/export function, leading to some weird error that it misses exactly one line string (in this case: the number "6") in the finished PDF/picture. Tried various possible fixes, playing around with the settings in producing the PDF, exporting as picture, but to no avail. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

E: Using a larger offset was the solution!

Visible in layout manager:

[image: Visible in the layout manager]

The finished PDF or picture:

[image: In the finished PDF]

Label settings atm:

[image: Label]

Comment: Please provide the label settings.

Comment: I have also tried changing the placement of the string, priority or changing text size

Also checked for validity of the geometry itself, which sometimes leads to weirdness

Comment: What happens if you change the number from "6" to "7"?

Comment: @bugmenot123 still doesn't show...

Comment: Did you try to check the "Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)" in the Rendering tab ? or the "Show all labels for all layers" in the Placement engine setting ?

Comment: Just tried it out, same result

Comment: What happens when you change the scale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the offset of 0.1 millimeters that you are using at the moment might be too small, I tried with a random set of polygons using "Outside Polygons" as a Mode and 0.1 millimeters as the distance the same way you did and half of the polygon IDs (polygons with labels "1", "4" and "6" out of 7 in total) didn't show on the exported PDF map. I tried again with a distance of 1 millimeter and all polygon IDs now appear on the final map. Does that work for you using a bigger distance?

[image]